# Morphing while spinning

Tags: particles, animation-nodes

Is it possible to morph while rotating the emitter?

I am trying to morph two objects by referring to the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4k7zClCcE8

It succeeds when the emitter is stationary, but fails when the emitter rotates or moves. (I attached the .blend file of the failure example)

Then I tried it with AnimationNodes in another file.
I wondered if I could make it look like it was morphing by using the "Offset Polygon" node.
It is my image that the face of one object becomes smaller and the face of the other object becomes larger.
However, I didn't know how to control FallOff of this node with UVMap.
I want to control the effect according to the UVMap, such as the general time of particles.
For example, the larger the value in the X direction in UVMap, the faster the effect will appear.

I've tried two methods, but I'm having problems with both.
Can you tell me about either solution?

I would appreciate it if you could reply.

[image]

Comment: i just added a z-rotation to your emitter - it just works. So maybe you should clarify your question and tell us how you did the rotation animation? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kIWN.gif

Comment: Thank you for your comment.Sorry,I seem to have uploaded the wrong file.
I uploaded the file again.

Comment: In the video I referred to, it seems that I'm morphing by duplicating several objects and switching the timing of each explode modifier.
This may have been a mistake as I was trying to set an explode modifier on an object to morph it.

Comment: It seems to be a known bug that it is not affected by texture when keyed
Maybe 3.0 has a fix? Https://developer.blender.org/T88715
I played it in reverse with VSE and cut and pasted the rice field and tried to make it by force
https://youtu.be/jj7p2UnMbVI